# On norm of the Sobolev space $H^2(\Omega)$, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n; n \geq 2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, sobolev-spaces

Let the Sobolev space $H^2(\Omega)$ be defined with the norm $\|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)}=\Big(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq 2})\|D^{\alpha}u\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}\Big)^\frac{1}{2}$.
I have found in several research articles that if a function $u \in L^2(\Omega)$, $\nabla u \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$ then $u \in H^2(\Omega)$. How does this conclusion hold? what absorbs the mixed partial derivative?

Please help me with references.

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is "elliptic regularity".

Comment: But elliptic regularity requires some boundary condition on u. As stated, the claim is false.

Comment: If you assume that the functions are compactly supported, then this can be proved easily using integration by parts.

Comment: But this question should be moved to math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

As Jochen mentioned, this is a consequence of regularity for the Poisson equation, at least for a regular domain ($C^2$ would suffices, I don't know if one can take less regularity such as $C^{1,1}$ or $C^{1,\alpha}$.).

Indeed, if one set $f = -\Delta u$ and $g = u_{|\partial \Omega}$ then by definition of the trace and the fact that $u \in H^1(\Omega)$, one has $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $g \in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ (i.e. the image of $H^1$ under the trace operator). Then regularity gives you $u \in H^2(\Omega)$ (see thm 8.12 of *Elliptic partial differential equations of second order* by D. Gilbard and N. S. Trudinger).

Note that the assumption $\nabla u \in L^2(\Omega)$ can't be dropped for general domain, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347047/are-there-l2-functions-whose-laplacian-is-in-l2-yet-its-gradient-is-not-in), except when $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^d$ (or in the torus) where one can use Fourier transform to obtain easily the result.

Comment: You need $g\in H^{3/2}$ to get $u \in H^2$. As stated the result does not hold and one can construct counterexamples with holomorphic functions in the unit disc (write the power series and the norm in terms of the coefficients).